# How to paint JPanel inside JFrame | Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, repaint

I have a JFrame that includes buttons,menu and JPanel. one of the buttons opens a new JFrame which needs to receive some information about the creation of the the JPanel. click on "OK" in this panel suppose to show some draw on the JPanel immediately. I succeed to do that but it cause a problem- the paintComponent called in endless loop and doesen't work unless repaint method called into the paintComponent method.
How can I fix that? thanks for helpers.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (createRoadSys != null) {
        if (createRoadSys.getFlag()) {
            for (Road r : createRoadSys.getD().getMap().getRoads()) {
                if (r.getEnable()) {
                    g.drawLine((int) r.getStartJunction().getX() + 4,
                               (int) r.getStartJunction().getY() - 3,
                               (int) r.getEndJunction().getX() + 4,
                               (int) r.getEndJunction().getY() - 2);
                }
            }
            for (Junction j : createRoadSys.getD().getMap().getJunctions()) {
                if (j instanceof LightedJunction) {
                    if (((LightedJunction) j).getLights().getTrafficLightsOn())
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    else
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillOval((int) j.getX(), (int) j.getY(), RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);
            }
            driving = createRoadSys.getD();
            isMapCreated = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < driving.getVehicles().size(); i++) {
                drawRotetedVehicle(g,
                                   (int) driving.getVehicles().get(i).getLastRoad().getStartJunction().getX(),
                                   (int) driving.getVehicles().get(i).getLastRoad().getStartJunction().getY(),
                                   (int) driving.getVehicles().get(i).getLastRoad().getEndJunction().getX(),
                                   (int) driving.getVehicles().get(i).getLastRoad().getEndJunction().getY(), 10, 8);
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `repaint()` within `paintComponent`.  Set up a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) to invoke `repaint()`

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

int milliseconds = 100;  // between timer calls.
Timer timer = new Timer(milliseconds, (ae)->repaint());
timer.start();
```

If you want to do more within the timer, set up an actionListener and use an instance of that as the second argument to your timer.

And make certain you do most of your processing outside the EDT (where the painting is done).  In other words, keep computations within `paintComponent` to a minimum.